# Limiting AND grouping in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to figure out a query on sqlite to solve my problems and absolve my sins in the eyes of my boss, so...

I have a table with 70 000 000 rows

one of the columns in the table are domains (called domain)
another column is called sourceurl (which is the full url string of which the column domain is the domain of the url)

For the most part source Url is unique and domain is not and you can have a multitude of source urls from the same domain.

The same table also contains other columns which are flags such as redirect,frame,mention,nofollow,alttext

What I need is to have a query which does the following:

Ignores any of the flags that are null, of the resulting data I would like to group all the remaining rows but then only select a maximum of 10 from each domain.

So at the end of the day I need 10 sample urls from each domain, and those sample urls need to exclude the flags that are NOT null.

Comment: How about sharing what you have tried so far? This isn't really a SQL lite specific question, more of a basic SQL question.

Comment: This is a pretty basic question a quick google brings up the stackoverflow answers. 0 for research skills.

Comment: I believe your description is confusing. On one hand, you say "*Ignores any of the flags that are null*", one the other, "*need to exclude the flags that are NOT null*".  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT domain,
       sourceurl
FROM MyTable AS T1
WHERE redirect <> 0  -- or whatever funny thing you want to do with the flags
  AND rowid <= IFNULL((SELECT rowid
                       FROM MyTable AS T2
                       WHERE T2.domain = T1.domain
                         AND redirect <> 0  -- same flags filter
                       ORDER BY rowid
                       LIMIT 1
                       OFFSET 9), 'inf')
```

(You need an index on the `domain` column for this to be somewhat efficient.)

Answer (score -1):

- Use LIMIT 10 at the end of the SQL to restrict the number of rows
  returned.
- Use !ifnull function around your flags to restrict the rows
  to those containing data.

Comment: The question asks for 10 records *per group*, not 10 records overall.